# Using fabric how can I supply a password for psql?

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-web-services, fabric, amazon-rds

I want to be able to log in to my AWS postgres database from a remote machine. I am using the following `Fabric` script:

```
import sys
from fabric.api import env, run, abort

env.port = 123
env.use_ssh_config = True

def setuser(user):
    """Sets the ssh user for the fabric script"""
    env.user = user
    env.password = 'mypassword'

def setenv(server):
    """Sets the environment for the fabric script"""
    env.hosts = ['staging']

def sync():
    # log into AWS server
    run("psql --host=staging.xxx.rds.amazonaws.com --username=x_user  --port=5432 --password --dbname=x_database")
    run("mypassword")
```

I run this `Fabric` script using the following command:

```
fab -f sync_staging.py sync --password=mypassword
```

This logs me into the remote machine, runs the line `run("psql ....` and then it prompts me for a password:

```
[stage] out: Password for user x_user:
```

Is there any way that I can supply the password (or respond to the prompt) such that it logs me in automatically?

Comment: Did you try to set the database configuration to `trust` in the pg_hba.conf file? I am not sure, but I though that is required for psql not to ask for a password.

Comment: I'm not able to edit the `pg_hba.conf` file as AWS does not allow it.

Comment: I just checked on the RDS console, unter "parameter groups", you can change a bunch of parameters and there is a "is modifiable" flag. The hba.conf file is not modifiable, so it might not be possible to allow an IP to access without password.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 ways of solving this that I know of:

- [.pgpass password file](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/libpq-pgpass.html) in your home directory on remote host
- [PGPASSWORD env variable](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/libpq-envars.html) (set on remote host)

If you need to set an environment variable on remote host, use `with shell_env(PGPASSWORD='mypassword')`, Fabric docs here: [fabric.context_managers.shell_env](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.6/api/core/context_managers.html?highlight=shell_env#fabric.context_managers.shell_env)

Hope it solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Just tried using `run('export PGPASSWORD=mypassword') but this does not work.

Comment: Fantastic! `with context_managers.shell_env(PGPASSWORD='mypassword')` worked.